# get length of `wchar_t*` in c++

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t

Please, how can I find out the length of a variable of type `wchar_t*` in c++?

code example below:

```
wchar_t* dimObjPrefix = L"retro_";
```

I would like to find out how many characters `dimObjPrefix` contains

Comment: Do you mean a single character or a string?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. I wanted the number of characters. wcslen seems to do what I want according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax(VS.71).aspx

Thanks tusbar.

Comment: @Jacob: a `wchar_t` is not a  string, and it doesn't have a length. I assume you're asking about `wchar_t*`. Those asterisks aren't just for show, you know. They can't be left out without changing the meaning of the code (and the question)

Comment: @jalf thanks and sorry. I have edited the question to include a code sample of what I was trying to find, with asterisks included.

Comment: Edited question to show proper `L""` syntax for wide strings.

Comment: So you want the length of the block of memory that a `wchar_t*` points to.

Comment: @Tomalak, no. From the question - "I would like to find out how many characters dimObjePrefix contains". Number of characters, not length of the block of memory. Plus this question has been marked as answered for almost a year.

Comment: @Jacob: You're right; I guess I was generalising. I meant to talk about a function of the length of the block of memory that the `wchar_t*` points to, with a focus on that the size of the pointer is irrelevant, and that the pointer itself contains no characters. Meanwhile, I wasn't aware that there was a time limit on contributing to SO questions; can you point me to that entry in the FAQ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to know the size of a *`wchar_t` string* (`wchar_t *`), you want to use [`wcslen(3)`](http://man.cx/wcslen(3)):

```
size_t wcslen (const wchar_t *ws);
```

Comment: Perhaps sizeof (wchar_t), or wchar_t x followed by sizeof x?

Comment: @Joseph, it took me a long time to realize what you meant, I edited. Thank you. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Regarding sizeof(), neither K&R nor the ANSI Rationale give any reason for this idiosyncrasy about parentheses; does any SO reader happen to know?

Comment: `sizeof(type)` versus `sizeof expression`. Now if `e` is an expression, then `(e)` is also an expression, so `sizeof (expression)` is implicitly also allowed.

Comment: Is it safe to use `wcslen`?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you want to get the length of null terminated C style string, you have two options:

1. `#include <cwchar>` and use `std::wcslen (dimObjPrefix);`,
2. or `#include <string>` and use `std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length (dimObjPrefix);`.