# how to check if corba::WString is empty?

Tags: c++, corba, wstring

Searched for this everywhere and finally came here. I have a CORBA::WString_var as input parameter to my function. How do I know if it's empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to consult your ORB vendor's documentation. If your ORB maps `CORBA::WChar` to `std::wchar_t`, then you can use the techniques in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853615/get-length-of-wchar-t-in-c/2857478#2857478).

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time ago. But if I remember correctly you can cast the WString_var to a WCHAR* and check this for NULL.

Comment: You can't pass null strings across an IDL interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use variable.in() to get the pointer to the CORBA::WChar array, than you can check that